# Странное поведение деструктора С++

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Код:

```
shared_ptr<People> func() noexcept
{
    shared_ptr<People> p = make_shared<Man>();
    return p; //1
}

int main() noexcept
{
    shared_ptr<People> pep = func();
    pep->Speak();

    return 0;
}
```

На строчке под комментарием 1 должен вызываться деструктор объекта p, но этого не происходит и код работает, почему?

Comment: Не должен - если компилятор свежий - промежуточный объект `p` просто не создается.

Comment: @Harry то есть код работает только благодаря оптимизации компилятора?

Comment: Не помню уж (потому и не даю ответом :)) с какого именно стандарта это обязательное поведение, которое раньше было разрешенной оптимизацией.

Comment: Даже если бы деструктор объекта p вызывался, никакой разницы в поведении программы бы не было, так как счетчик ссылок все равно бы имел значение 1.

Comment: это [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  с 17 стандарта уже требуется. До этого компиляторы сами делали. А тут - https://habr.com/ru/post/277333/ можно почитать увлекательную историю, как человек решил выстрелить в ногу, но не срослось

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision RVO наверно вмешалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Деструктор не вызывается из-за оптимизации компилятора (см. copy elision). В случаях когда применить её невозможно, из метода будет возвращена копия p, поэтому всё будет работать в любом случае.